# PHP Redirect on Login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I am trying to setup a simple PHP login script that redirects after successful login. The problem is that the header call only works after a successful login followed by a manual refresh. The only answer for this problem I have found on SO is "do not echo content before the call to header", however I do not believe I am. I did read that session_start sends headers but if I move that to after the call to isset, the page doesnt redirect after refresh, leading me to believe the session variable is not set.

```
 <?php session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['logged']))
 {
      header("Location: index.html");
      exit;
 }



     function BuildLogin(){

          include("passwords.php"); 
          if ($_POST["ac"]=="log") { /// do after login form is submitted  
             if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) { 
                 $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"]; 
             } else { 
                echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.'; 
             }; 
          }; 
          if (!array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) {  
               echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
               echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" />'; 
               echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" />'; 
               echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
               echo '</form>'; 
          }; 
    }
 ?>

 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
 <title>File Management</title>
 <style type="text/css">/* IE has layout issues when sorting (see #5413) */
 .group { zoom: 1 }

 body{
     padding:0px 25px 25px 25px;
 }


 #content {
     background-color:#989898;
     box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     border-top-right-radius: 4px;
     border-top-left-radius: 4px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
     padding:25px 25px 25px 25px;
     height:auto;
     overflow:auto;
     }




 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="content">
 <?php BuildLogin(); ?>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Thanks to TheBeacon for the solution. Here is the updated version of the PHP**

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST["ac"]) && !empty($_POST) && $_POST["ac"]=="log") {  
      include("passwords.php"); 
      if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) { 
         $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"];
         header('Location: index.html');
     }; 
 }; 


function BuildLogin(){

    include("passwords.php"); 
    if (isset($_POST["ac"]) && !empty($_POST) && $_POST["ac"]=="log") { 
        echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.';  
    }; 
    if (!array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) {  
        echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
        echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" />'; 
        echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" />'; 
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
        echo '</form>'; 
    }; 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Is there anything in your PHP logs?

Comment: Sorry I am new to PHP. How do I veiw them?

Comment: Depends on your OS. Just google your OS and PHP logs.

Comment: I think you have to redirect after login.

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); at the top of the PHP section and no errors are reported after login. There are two prior to login for 'logged' and 'ac' not set, but that is expected prior to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put following code **at top of page instead of inside function**

```
 if (isset($_POST["ac"]) && !empty($_POST) && $_POST["ac"]=="log") 
 { /// do after login form is submitted  

   if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) 
   { 
     $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"]; 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.'; 
   }
 }
```

**before**

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['logged']))
 {
      header("Location: index.html");
      exit;
 }
```

Comment: Wow. I'm a newbie to PHP but I should have caught that the function only executes after content is loaded. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're currently using UTF8 encoded text.

When saving text in UTF8, some editor(like notepad.exe) will automatically add [BOM(Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your file, which consists of three bytes: EF BB BF. It's invisible when you're editing, but PHP will regard these bytes as a part of HTML content. So PHP will flush HTTP header and begin outputting response body, then you can't call `header()` function to redirect page.

Some source editors, such as Nodepad++/Sublime Text/UltraEdit, provide a feature to save UTF8 encoded text without BOM. For example, in Notepad++ you can just click **Encoding** -> **Encode in UTF8 without BOM** to fix it.

[image: To encoded as UTF-8 without BOM in Notepad++]